# How to re-direct the contents to a file instead of printing it to terminal

Tags: perl

How to avoid printing the contents to terminal (As it will take more time if it is 20k lines in my case) and instead redirect it to a file in perl?

This is just a sample and not the entire code:

```
 if ($count eq $length)
                {
                    push(@List,$line);
                    print "$line\n"; #Prints line to terminal which is time consuming
                }
```

I tried below but it did not work

```
if ($cnt eq $redLen)
                    {
                        push(@List,$line);
                        print $line > "/home/vibes/text";
                    }
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear?

Comment: Are you asking how to print to a file instead of standard output? Or are you asking how to call something (e.g. a perl script) with output redirection? Both seems so simple a question that I deduce that your phrasing of what you actually need is unclear. If you are asking one of the two things, then your question qualifies as "not helpful or unclear and does not show any research effort"; which is of course the definition of when to click the downvote button. In your favor I bet on "unclear".

Comment: I meant to ask how to print to a file instead of standard output? Sorry If I was not clear at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the [3 argument](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) open method.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "Hello Again!";
open (my $fh, ">", "/home/vibes/text") || die "Failed to open /home/vibes/text $!";
print $fh "$line\n";
close($fh); # Always close opened files.
```

Answer (score -2):

The default filehandle in perl is `STDOUT`. You can change it with a call to [`select`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#select):

```
print "Hello\n";          # goes to stdout

open my $fh, '>', '/home/vibes/text';
select($fh);

print "World\n";          # goes to file '/home/vibes/text'
```

From your shell, output redirection is usually a matter of appending `> file` to your command. This is true in both Unix-y systems and on Windows.

```
$ perl my_script.pl > /home/vibes/text
```

Comment: the better method `open (my $fh, ">", "/home/vibes/text") || die "Failed to open /home/vibes/text $!";` and also always `close($fh);`